# Is this max function decent?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

I am trying to understand new c++ features and I came up with my implementation of max function:

```
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
concept bool Comparable() {
    return requires(T a, T b) 
    {
        {a > b} -> bool;
        {a < b} -> bool;
        {a >= b} -> bool;
        {a <= b} -> bool;
    };
}

template<Comparable T, Comparable U>
constexpr decltype(auto) max(T&& a, U&& b)
{
    return std::forward<T>(a) > std::forward<U>(b) ? std::forward<T>(a) : std::forward<U>(b);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int a = 2, b = 3;

    return max(a, b);
}
```

Can this replace the macro version?

```
#define MAX(a, b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
```

And if not what can be improved?

I am compiling with `gcc-8.1.0` and `-std=c++2a`, `-fconcepts` and `-O3` flags

## EDIT:

Thank you for your suggestions, this is how it looks now:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename U>
concept bool TypesLessComparable() {
    return requires(T a, U b)
    {
        {a < b} -> bool;
    };
}

template<typename T, typename U>
constexpr decltype(auto) max(T&& a, U&& b) requires (TypesLessComparable<T, U>() == true)
{
    return a < b ? std::forward<U>(b) : std::forward<T>(a);
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int a = 2, b = 3;

    return max(a, b);
}
```

Comment: for code reviews you might want to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your `Comparable` is really constraining for a simple `max`, requiring `{a > b} -> bool;` would be sufficient. And it is more usual to use `<` rather than `>` for such operations.

Comment: btw anything is better than a macro :P

Comment: "Is this max function decent?" no it is not

Comment: @Slava why isn't it?

Comment: i dont know concepts but I find it a bit strange that you require that much. To compare two values all you need is `<`. why all those other operators?

Comment: I put them there because the concept isn't named properly. 'Comparable' should check for all of these (imho). I also implemented a few other functions to experiment with concepts and I forgot to simplify the code for this question :)

Comment: @AlexandruIca Why should it check for all of those?  I can compare with just `operator <`.  I can even tell you if two objects are equal with just `operator <`.

Comment: Just use [std::max()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max) already.

Comment: `'Comparable' should check for all of these (imho).` That makes sense. However, in that case `max` should not require `Comparable` but something like `LessThanComparable` instead.

Comment: @JesperJuhl [`std::max` has the pesky problem of not being able to work with `std::max(1, 2.0);`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/071176d600d06d0a)

Comment: @NathanOliver Yeah, If I come to think about it you are right, Jesper: of course I would use the standard function in a real project but here I am just experimenting.

Answer (score 3):

> Is this max function decent?

No, there are at least 3 issues:

1 Unclear why you request multiple comparison operations when your function only requires one of them (it should be fine for a `class` only to define `operator>` when only `max()` is used)

2 Concept `Comparable` requires that type has comparison operations on itself, you may compare 2 object of different types. This invalidates usage of concepts (a function should use only what required/provided by concepts)

3 You may return objects of different types as well, one may convert to another but you should cover that by another concept.

Here is code example for case 2 and 3:

```
 struct A { friend bool operator>( const A&, const A& ); };
 struct B { friend bool operator>( const B&, const B& ); };

 auto x = max( A(), B() );
```

To summarize:

- Your function should require minimum set of operations on type(s), necessary for it to operate.
- If type(s) passed concepts validation your function should compile successfully.

This is most probably not full set of requirements.

Comment: I agree with the first one. If I got it right for the second one(requires should have T a and U b?), the code doesn't compile, and I don't understand the 3rd point.

Comment: @AlexandruIca added code sample for 2 and 3, see what happens in this case - both `classes` satisfy your concept, but function fails to compile

Comment: I am not too experienced in C++ but why should the function compile in that case?

Comment: @AlexandruIca it should not compile, but compilation should be rejected by a concept not template instantiation, otherwise there is no reason to provide any.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> std::forward<T>(a) > std::forward<U>(b) ? std::forward<T>(a) : std::forward<U>(b);
> ```

You forward the result twice. This is wrong for most types (only OK for types that implement move as a deep copy). You should remove forward from the comparison.

Comment: If your `operator>` is correctly implemented (i.e., taking const-references), this should not be an issue in practice. But I agree that these two first `std::forward` should be removed.